# Covariant Spin Operator for Massless Fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, research-level, spin-statistics

I have been reading the paper [The Covariant Definition Of Spin in Relativistic QFT](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272698/1-s2.0-S0031891400X01991/1-s2.0-0031891465901412/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEG8aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCQSLlDu5I7BZCUCABw%2BS4hrywIr1%2Bt5deS0NO0v3yNRwIgSFV6%2FRSer2em6KI7UVCE%2FKgsTxH3ik7I6GzYj091rJYqswUISBAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDJaZt3w2vSgM18IsDiqQBTcXTFdrfLZ8%2Bks4aEPT8e69Fc%2FxhH1tV6eatZmboM529t816dUgH5BgWrxe2Iq%2BkvuQ2%2B5ysJ7F2XtlKmjRP7ILSUrbEK%2F36KryQDwRJhYsJBXh0%2F1CwsXKCDkDipKMAIICvfeMb5plGCf02LMgrWkfsSbCqW%2FwZBQ%2BUOs%2BxPssOGcAHuyzu2sDtVqbQedeQYcKH0lssgnNUDtTOoLYgJn3wfM9tQLfTrEO%2FObNQaEPzXeLiYgqWfO%2BYx5S5pctzbVPh0uA73bsB%2BgjX6qshsNSSfWdLK7DCcJK6aob99YEymzJJQuccbpcYtNmvwLAWT%2F71a1s%2BQVNV%2BVwo3ZIYc4JZLhoGDGNQHEha4mRfP1nltZ%2F3hvDShiswVQ5t1Ozs1wOQsSFkHR%2BhOfwu3p1DpnJnBeNvRFpCuP4bJ1Nkn5TWvbwKIKzDdT9UEKY9gUF%2FqA7WcGF1kSw1da%2FIF9bKhEVx9IPqYLVb1qFiZWDSL6iqrYs%2FM%2B4XQ2EBHfSPiesfSpGffW%2BXZQVGx30cHT6USCfNcb9znY6rce8Vy84LxfTKrvjVHpDoOBCf8wg08hcgc19G169NLPNaZ6I4XwbnH%2BkEU%2BN25lj9WKwxPhIdrkplfx9GlOo7Kvjp6zPcL0xFw9vTUXZ%2BON9%2FluqFMlOVib8ceG5iAhBtxoWDizeKl%2FEeZNcgWLwRS1To%2FcPj3xrr09qFN972SWlgo6OcelEIlelwFCRzFbOzZeqCse2CtfELz7YyN%2BvDdyFAmC1xEyEtIAT%2FYVQU1MCgotihY%2BDMvXILPYifF7UF0auE7adnUDm8EdWrqNY%2BFyjaTngPKyW%2F164rMxuM75yegp%2F4AcwR7ZxH0lP82Frkv7HtWG6MQG4MOvY16cGOrEBB0Dm8DvOEDgIhLSvDoTylHgl%2FH%2BZDiVcQE1QabRf15ES8newMEsvxjOalM3FAX2KQOyznaLXS6VX3troPmuV0sknaafDTPAxDliAKW6%2F2Ihm7D191uawM0aR61fOIBL1qHM%2B%2F1ckKtoGhpZ7EE%2FhZi1YrEbfjT7iZbI4pW8ej5UOwEtB1Xq2SDXcP1c8wfna93rNd%2BvkWh%2Fxn0elwM6%2BGMoZPghlBUQzXJUWQbh7uWNz&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230904T151926Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY42V2VFGV%2F20230904%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=103e9ba17936be10fd9d3e9545127698834f7fdbb3a4bf4da1eb51ac230b5ba5&hash=75212983e7ecd260d75453a76d957cbd9d47f3ba56cbb9da06e84b8792518df4&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0031891465901412&tid=spdf-28bb2c9e-ae89-408a-8cde-4ef68c14414d&sid=b3fd818c6faa15496c6bc3e3b3d0495eb9b6gxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=061f5d5f555552500754&rr=801735f64affd300&cc=cy) by Hilgevoord and De Kerf, in which the authors derive the spin operator in relativistic quantum theories of free fields with nonvanishing rest mass and arbitrary spin.

1. To do that, they consider a Lagrangian of the form
   $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2m}(\partial_{\mu}\psi^{\dagger}\partial^{\mu}\psi-
   m^2\psi^{\dagger}\psi)$$
   from which they obtain the Klein-Gordon equations of motion for a spinor field. The benefit of this Lagrnangian is that the various components of the spinor field are decoupled (i.e. not mixed components from $\psi^{\dagger}$ with components from $\psi$).
2. They further support that, being written like that as opposed to the Dirac Lagrangian, $\mathcal{L}$ gives rise to a symmetric energy-momentum tensor
   $T^{\mu\nu}=\sum_rc_rT^{\mu\nu}_r$, where $r$ is the $r-$th component of the spinor field, and
   $$T^{\mu\nu}_r=\frac{1}{2m}(\partial^{\mu}\psi^{\dagger}_r\partial^{\nu}\psi_r
   +\partial^{\nu}\psi^{\dagger}_r\partial^{\mu}\psi_r)-
   g^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$$
3. As a last step, they use $S^{\mu\nu}=\int d^3xf^{0\mu\nu}$, where
   $$f^{\lambda\mu\nu}=\sum_{r,s}
   \frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta(\partial_{\lambda}\psi_r)}
   \frac{1}{4}(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}-\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu})^r_s
   \psi^s$$
   and they obtain by using the Dirac equation the expectation value of the spin components of the Dirac field
   $$S^{\mu\nu}=\int d^3x\ \psi^{\dagger}\Big[
   \frac{i}{4}(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}-\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu})+
   \frac{1}{2m}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}-\gamma^{\nu}\partial^{\mu})\Big]\psi$$
   and from there they define the Spin operator as
   $$S_{op}^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{4}(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}-\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu})+
   \frac{1}{2m}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}-\gamma^{\nu}\partial^{\mu})$$

**How to apply this procedure to the case of a massless fermion?**

From what I understand, the overall mass parameter in the denominator of $\mathcal{L}$ is inserted there such that $\psi$ has mass dimensions $[M]=3/2$, correctly describing thus, spinor fields while they obey at the same time the Klein-Gordon equation (and hence the energy-momentum tensor decouples and therefore, is symmetric). This is the price to pay so that one is able to define a covariant spin tensor. Therefore, one can not re-scale the Lagrangian if one wants the KG equation to be satisfied and hence, the massless case can not be studied. **Is my understanding correct, or is there some sort of reconciliation? I can think of two possible senarios:**

1. One can insert another energy parameter, instead of $m$ in the Lagrangian overall denominator (say $p^0$) or
2. one has to symmetrize the energy-momentum tensor in some other fashion.

**Can anyone comment on that? How to construct a covariant spin tensor for massless spinors?**